# Ruby Enumeration: Taken first n where block returns true

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I want to take the first "n" entries which pass the block

```
a = 1..100_000_000 # Basically a long array

# This iterates over the whole array -- no good
b = a.select{|x| x.expensive_operation?}.take(n)
```

I want to short circuit the iteration once i've got n entries where 'expensive' condition is true.

What do you suggest? take_while and keep count of n?

```
# This is the code i have; which i think can be written better, but how?
a = 1..100_000_000 # Basically a long array
n = 20
i = 0
b = a.take_while do |x|
  ((i < n) && (x.expensive_operation?)).tap do |r|
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: I seems to me that your solution selects some `x` value even if `x.expensive_operation?` is false... is that what you want ?

Comment: hmm..you're right that my solution doesnt seem right but not in the way you're suggesting.it will stop at first value where expensive_operation is false returning me less than n values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 implements [lazy enumerables](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/), for older versions use the gem [enumerable-lazy](https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy):

```
require 'enumerable/lazy'
(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.select(&:even?).take(5).to_a
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with a simple `for` loop and a `break` :

```
a = 1..100_000_000 # Basically a long array
n = 20
selected = []
for x in a
  selected << x if x.expensive_operation?
  break if select.length == n
end
```