# Find first n elements from array that match a condition

Tags: ruby

I want to select the first 10 elements of an array that match a certain condition without having to loop through the whole array. I know that [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) gets me the first element. So for example, the code below gives me the first prime that is larger than 100:

```
require 'prime'

puts Prime.find {|p| p > 100 } #=> 101
```

Is there a way to get the first 10 primes that are bigger then 100?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ruby 2.0+ you can write:

```
require 'prime'

Prime.lazy.select{|p| p > 100 }.take(10).to_a #=> [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. To add to your answer: this [answer provides some more info on the lazy operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108521/ruby-enumeration-taken-first-n-where-block-returns-true#13108529).

Comment: That also does not perform well for very high lower bounds.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it more manually like

```
def check_for_primes(start_number, desired_size)
  result = []
  suspect = start_number
  while result.size < desired_size do
    result << suspect if suspect.prime?
    suspect += 1
  end
  result
end

check_for_primes 100, 10

#=> [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149]
```

with a simple ruby iteration.

Which works with all ruby versions.

instead of the (indisputably non ruby like) while loop, we can add **@cary-swoveland** 's variation, which has quite some ruby goodness in it.

```
check_enum_text(start_number, desired_size)
  (start_number..1.0/0).each_with_object([]) do |n,arr|
    if n.prime?
      arr << n;
      return arr if arr.size == desired_size
    end
  end
end
```

*************UPDATE*************

and some benchmarks for performance

```
require 'benchmark'
a_gazillion = 10000000000

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("lazy_select") { Prime.lazy.select{|p| p > (a_gazillion / 1000) }.take(10).to_a }
  x.report("prime_each") { arr = []; Prime.each{|p| arr << p if p > a_gazillion / 1000; break if arr.count == 10 } }
  x.report("while_loop") { check_for_primes a_gazillion, 10 }
  x.report("enum_text") { check_enum_text a_gazillion, 10 }
end

            user       system     total     real
lazy_select 75.360000   0.240000  75.600000 (84.259781)
prime_each  6.100000    0.040000   6.140000 ( 6.730646)
while_loop  0.620000    0.000000   0.620000 ( 0.655504)
enum_text   0.610000    0.000000   0.610000 ( 0.770726)
```

from what we see the two latest solutions are the ones that perform the best. From some extra benchmarking (by tweaking the desired_size) I can not conclude to which one is better

```
def bench(start, length)
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report("enum_text") { check_enum_text start, length }
    x.report("while_loop") { check_for_primes start, length}
  end
end

bench a_gazillion, 100
             user       system    total     real
enum_text    6.350000   0.000000   6.350000 (  6.974557)
while_loop   6.530000   0.000000   6.530000 (  7.330884)

bench a_gazillion, 500
             user        system     total        real
enum_text    31.880000   0.110000  31.990000 ( 36.723209)
while_loop   32.850000   0.060000  32.910000 ( 38.569744)
```

Performance is similar (actually **@cary-swoveland**'s solution performs slightly better), so I will have to go with that solution since it is more ruby like!!

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the benchmarks! Point is the condition I am checking for is not `> 100`. It is [another boolean check](http://projecteuler.net/problem=37) with way more logic than that. Specifically: `class Integer
  def is_truncable?
   truncable = true
    str, str2= self.to_s, self.to_s
    if self == 2 || self == 3 || self == 5 || self == 7 then return false end
    while str.size > 0
      if !Prime.prime?(str.to_i) || !Prime.prime?(str2.to_i) then truncable = false end
      str = str.chop
      str2 = str2[1..-1]
    end
    truncable
  end
end` Don't think your method can be used here

Comment: well yes, but that is not the question in this thread... If you want you can add an extra question for that.

Comment: `You could spice it up a bit by replacing the body of the method with (start_number..1.0/0).each_with_object([]) do |n,arr| if n.prime?; arr << n; return arr if arr.size == desired_size; end; end; end`.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could add the method I suggested to your benchmark.  Perhaps call it, `enum_next`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I did benchmark it, check the results! BTW nice code up there!

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = []
Prime.each{|p| arr << p if p > 100; break if arr.count == 10 }
puts arr
```

Comment: Thanks works as well. Probably faster than the lazy implementation.

Comment: That can't be efficient because you also check for all the numbers that are lower than the lower bound. It will not perform for higher lower bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers have the disadvantage that they enumerate primes below the threshold multiple times.  Here is one way to avoid that:

```
require 'prime'

def check_for_primes(start_number, desired_size)
  return [] if desired_size.zero?
  enum = Prime.each
  [enum.find { |n| n >= start_number }] + enum.first(desired_size-1)
end    

check_for_primes(100, 10)
  #=> [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149]
```

Alternatively, this could be written:

```
def check_for_primes(start_number, desired_size)
  return [] if desired_size.zero?
  enum = Prime.each
  (0..1.0/0).each_with_object([]) do |_,arr|
    n = enum.next
    if n >= start_number
      arr << n 
      return arr if arr.size == desired_size
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is pretty nice! You can change the iterator to `each_with_object([]) do |_,arr|` since you override `n` without using it at all.

Comment: Good point, xlembouras. Fixed that. Using the same variable for both may have been confusing as well.  And thanks for the benchmarks.  Looks like style won out over substance.

Answer (score 1):

A simple iterative way:

```
require 'prime'

initial = 100
list = []

10.times do |x|
    initial = Prime.find {|p| p > initial}
    list << initial
end

puts list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Prime.each(n)` to have an upper limit:

```
Prime.each(1000).drop_while { |p| p <= 100 }.take(10)
# => [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149]
```

Alternatively, you can count have many primes are *below* 100, then take that amount + 10:

```
Prime.take(Prime.take_while { |p| p <= 100 }.count + 10)[-10..-1]
# => [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149]
```